# Do not run CSS animation on first load

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

The first image should not fade in when the user loads the page. It should only fade in after the first and subsequent cycles are completed. I basically want the first image to fully appear right away on page load.

HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="VirtualBox_Fedora_12_11_2017_02_22_46.png">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="25945941662_d9a450d7ef_b.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="img3.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}
.mySlides.fade img {
  /*background: */
  display: block;
  height: 60vh;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fade {
  animation-duration: 1.0s;
  animation-name: fade;
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .6}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

JS:

```
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe using data attributes can be useful for enabling/disabling animations in general...

```js
var slideIndex = 0
, slides = document.getElementsByClassName('mySlide');
slides[slideIndex].style.display = 'block';
setTimeout(showNextSlide, 5000);
function showNextSlide() {
 var l = slides[slideIndex++];
 l.dataset.dontAnimate = 0;
 l.style.display = 'none';
 if(slides.length == slideIndex)
  slideIndex = 0;
 slides[slideIndex].style.display = 'block';
 setTimeout(showNextSlide, 5000);
}
```

```css
.mySlide {
  display: none;
}
.mySlide img {
  display: block;
  height: 60vh;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fade:not([data-dont-animate="1"]) {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.0s;
}
@keyframes fade {
  from { opacity: 0.6 }
  to { opacity: 1 }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlide fade" data-dont-animate="1">
 <h1>
   Slide 1
 </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlide fade">
 <h1>
   Slide 2
 </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlide fade">
 <h1>
   Slide 3
 </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class for which will exempt the first `img` from the animation. **e.g.**

```
.fade:not(.first) {
  animation-duration: 1.0s;
  animation-name: fade;
}
```

Just be sure to remove the class after the initial load. Using something like the following:

```
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
    // the check
    if (slides[i].classList.contains('first')) {
      slides[i].classList.remove('first');
    }
}
```

Here's a working example: https://codepen.io/pablo-tavarez/pen/JONKrW